# How to translate numbers to other languages using interpolation method format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, localization, i18next, react-i18next

I'm new in using react i18next and was trying to translate texts, dates and number to other languages which I am able to change into via dropdown. The interpolation number format is not working over here as expected.

Here're my code pieces:

**App.tsx**

```
function HeaderComponent() {
  const [t] = useTranslation('common');
  const [val, setVal] = useState('en');
  window.moment = moment;
  return <div>
    <select
      value={val}
      onChange={(e) => {
        const vl = e.currentTarget.value;
        setVal(vl);
        changeLanguage(vl);
      }}
    >
      <option value="en">en</option>
      <option value="hi">in</option>
      <option value="bn">bn</option>
      <option value="mr">mr</option>
      <option value="es">es</option>
      <option value="de">de</option>
    </select>
    <h1>{t('welcome.title', { framework: 'React' })}</h1>
    <p>
      {t('date_format_two', { date: new Date() })}
    </p>
    <p>
      {t('number_one', { number: 10 })}
    </p>
  </div>
}
    
function App() {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback="loading">
      <div className="App">
        <HeaderComponent />
      </div>
    </Suspense>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**i18n.js**

```
i18next
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .use(ChainedBackend)
    .init({
        ns: ["common"],
        defaultNS: "common",
        fallbackLng: "en",
        debug: true,
        load: "languageOnly",
        returnObjects: true,
        joinArrays: true,
        cleanCode: true,
        interpolation: {
            format: (value, format, lng) => {
                // not getting the value for numbers here
                if (value instanceof Date) {
                    return moment().format(format);
                }
                if (typeof value === "number") {
                    return value.toLocaleString(lng);
                } 
                return value;
            },
            escapeValue: false
        },
        lng: 'en',                              // language to use
        react: {
            wait: true,
            useSuspense: false
        },
        backend: {
            backends: backends,
            backendOptions: backEndOptions
        }
    });
```

**utils/i18n.js**

```
export const backends = [XHRBackEnd];

export const loadPath = () => "/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json";

export const backEndOptions = [{ loadPath }];
```

**locales/en/common.json**

```
{
"welcome": {
        "title": "Welcome to {{framework}}!"
    },
    "date_format_one": "{{-date, YYYY/MM/DD}}",
    "date_format_two": "{{date, LL}}",
     "number_one": "Number is: {{ number }}"
}
```

**locales/es/common.json**

```
{
"welcome": {
        "title": "Bienvenido a {{framework}}!"
    },
    "date_format_one": "{{-date, YYYY/MM/DD}}",
    "date_format_two": "{{date, DD-MM-YYYY}}",
     "number_one": "Number is: {{ number }}"
}
```

How to achieve number translations using interpolation in react-i18next? Any help related to the issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

Needed to use comma (,) and the format in the json file like the following and its all working fine -

**locales/es/common.json**

```
{
"welcome": {
        "title": "Bienvenido a {{framework}}!"
    },
    "date_format_one": "{{-date, YYYY/MM/DD}}",
    "date_format_two": "{{date, DD-MM-YYYY}}",
     "number_one": "Number4 is: {{ number, format }}"
}
```

Posted this answer if it would be of help of somebody like me in future if the person is new in **react-i18next**.